# How to update specific rows in one dataframe that exist in another dataframe - Pyton/Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to migrate some of the SQL queries that we have to a Python script that would lately just insert to the DB all the latest updated data.

I have been trying to update the rows at particular places where the id exists in a dataframe, which for that I used numpy intersect and then updated the values, however I'm not sure how to update the values only at specific locations instead of looping through every single one.

Checking the pandas documentation I saw that they have a df.at syntax, but this updates the value based on the index number, which would be different than updating based on another type of id.

How could I update the values using .at or another syntax?

The SQL queries are simple updates that check if it's in a particular table and then update the status of the user. E.g:

```
UPDATE users
SET status = 'Active Customer'
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM logs)
AND id IS NOT NULL


UPDATE users
SET status = 'Non Active Customer'
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM logs)
AND id IS NOT NULL
AND status = 'Unknown'


UPDATE users
SET status = 'Active Customer (Calls)'
WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM calls)
AND id > 0
AND status = 'Unknown'
```

Here is a sample of what I have been trying in Jupyter

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


### creating a test DF
users_df = pd.DataFrame(
{'name':['Bob','Olivia','Gustav','Bella', 'Fran', 'Marco'],
 'user_id':['10',np.nan,'30','50','32',np.nan]
}
)

users_df["user_id"] = pd.to_numeric(users_df["user_id"])
users_df['status'] = 'Unknown'
users_df


### creating a log test DF
logs = pd.DataFrame(
{'user_id':['10','20','30','32','55']}
)
logs["user_id"] = pd.to_numeric(logs["user_id"])


### Updating the values in the status column -- updates everything instead of only certain rows
intersect = np.intersect1d(users_df['user_id'], logs['user_id'])
users_df['status'] = ['Active Customer' if x in intersect else 'Unknown' for x in users_df['user_id']]
users_df
```

Comment: this looks like a difficult approach.  try using set operations to find intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using Pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) property and [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method:

```py
# Updating the values in the status column
users_df.loc[
    users_df["user_id"].isin(logs["user_id"].values), "status"
] = "Active Customer"
```

Then:

```py
print(users_df)
# Output

     name  user_id           status
0     Bob     10.0  Active Customer
1  Olivia      NaN          Unknown
2  Gustav     30.0  Active Customer
3   Bella     50.0          Unknown
4    Fran     32.0  Active Customer
5   Marco      NaN          Unknown
```